# How to install filter for printer Canon pixma ip1900

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I installed driver for Canon ip1900. But printer doesn't print. It is not hardware issue.
In printer properties it is stated:
=> in "Parameters" "Processing page 1" and after that - "Stoppage - rendering completed";
=> in "Level of ink/toner" it is stated "missing print filter for "Canon-IP1900-series".
I do not know what to do.
Can someone help me? Driver was installed by system when I added a new printer. Version of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Kind regards.

Comment: Is this a hardware issue with the printer itself? This doesn't seem to really relate to Ubuntu.

Comment: Installed a driver from where ? (download link?) - how did you install it?  Which version of ubuntu?  Anything specifically you are trying to print?  From which application? - please edit your question with any replies.  Thanks.